# sudo apachectl start not working

Tags: apache

Before I could use terminal to start Apache service as:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

But recently it doesn't work, even after I restart my PC. Instead, I can use XAMPP to start Apache easily. Who can tell me why the terminal doesn't work at all?

Besides, since I'm a beginner with command line, I know the statement

`ps aux | grep httpd`

can show if apache is running. But I don't know the exact meaning of each field, like:

```
yy    1708   0.0  0.0  2432772    604 s000  R+    8:05PM   0:00.00 grep httpd
```

what does those numbers or characters mean? Is anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo apachectl configtest` to check that nothing prevents Apache from starting like a syntax error in one of its config files.

If it can't start, then it must throw an error in its log, check in `var/log/`, ususally there's a `apache2` or `httpd` folder there, containing error and access logs.

The numbers of the `ps aux` command are explained at the top of each column when you run this command without any `grep` pipe (which strips the header, because nothing matches `httpd` in the first line).

More info here: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ps_(Unix).

In your case, `httpd` is not obviously not running since you only get your own `grep` command as a result so the numbers don't really matter ;-)